# Node.JS performance vs native C++ addon when populating an Int32Array

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, performance

I've been experimenting with Node.JS and C++ addons and found that populating an Int32Array is considerably slower when using the C++ addon rather than directly doing so in Node.JS / JavaScript.

> Node.JS: 133 ~ ms
>   C++: 1103 ~ ms

Does anyone know why this is? My test code consists of a fairly large array and *for* loops containing *if* statements.

I suspect I'm populating the array incorrectly in my C++ addon. (?)

**JavaScript:**

```
var testArray = new Int32Array(36594368);

var i = 0;
for (var xi = 0; xi < 332; xi++) {
    for (var yi = 0; yi < 332; yi++) {
        for (var zi = 0; zi < 332; zi++) {
            if ((xi + yi + zi) % 62 == 0) testArray[i] = 2;
            else if (yi < 16) testArray[i] = 2;
            else if (yi == 16) testArray[i] = 1;
            else testArray[i] = 0;

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**C++ Addon:**

```
Local<Int32Array> testArray = Int32Array::New(ArrayBuffer::New(isolate, 4 * 36594368), 0, 36594368);

int i = 0;
for (int xi = 0; xi < 332; xi++) {
    for (int yi = 0; yi < 332; yi++) {
        for (int zi = 0; zi < 332; zi++) {
            if ((xi + yi + zi) % 62 == 0) testArray->Set(i, Integer::New(isolate, 2));
            else if (yi < 16) testArray->Set(i, Integer::New(isolate, 2));
            else if (yi == 16) testArray->Set(i, Integer::New(isolate, 1));
            else testArray->Set(i, Integer::New(isolate, 0));

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to add, the functions I'm using in my C++ code are V8 functions and weren't defined by myself. Is there another way to set values in an Int32Array without using these?

Comment: You're doing a massive number of function calls in C++, no code is given as to what those are doing, but just direct assignment in NodeJS. Also, what compiler settings are you using? Comparing C++ in completely unoptimized debug mode is not a fair test.

Comment: Thanks tadman. My C++ code is simply supposed to declare a V8 Int32Array and assign the values as per the JavaScript code, unless I'm doing this incorrectly. The addon is compiled as release (not debug mode) x64. If my C++ code is not equivalent to my JavaScript code an explanation on how I'm doing it wrong would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Maxing out Typed Array Performance using C++

I'm not surprised this is slow as written, but there is a lot you can do to speed it up.  The critical insight is that when dealing with JavaScript typed arrays in node, you can gain access to the memory buffer and operate on that directly.

### The main source of slowness

Though when dealing with normal JavaScript arrays/objects, the following are necessary

> Integer::New(*isolate*,*value*)

and

> testArray->Set(*value*)

So for example the following line

```
testArray->Set(i, Integer::New(isolate, 0));
```

creates a new *Number* object, converts the integer 0 to a double since all JavaScript numbers are double, calls **Set** with the *Number* object, then converts the double back to an integer because it's storing the value in a *Int32* typed array, and then destructs the Number object.  This happens 3 million times.

### An improvement

But typed arrays are different, and the call **GetIndexedPropertiesExternalArrayData** gives one access to the underlying buffer, which for a *Int32Array* is a buffer of *int*.  This allows the C++ function to be re-written to avoid all of those allocations and casts:

```
void doMkArray(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
   v8::Isolate *I = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
   Local<Int32Array> testArray = Int32Array::New(ArrayBuffer::New(I, 4 * 36594368),0,36594368);
   int *dptr = (int*)testArray->GetIndexedPropertiesExternalArrayData();

   int i = 0;
   for (int xi = 0; xi < 332; xi++)
   {
      for (int yi = 0; yi < 332; yi++)
      {
         for (int zi = 0; zi < 332; zi++)
         {
            if ((xi + yi + zi) % 62 == 0) dptr[i] = 2;
            else if (yi < 16) dptr[i] = 2;
            else if (yi == 16) dptr[i] = 1;
            else dptr[i] = 0;

            i++;
         }
      }
   }

   args.GetReturnValue().Set(testArray);
}
```

### Some measurements

Replacing with the above makes things faster, but how much faster needs a test.  The [following package](https://github.com/waTeim/array_test) can be cloned and when run (using node 0.12.5) results in the following

```
  Performance Tests
    ✓ via javascript (169ms)
    ✓ via c++ (141ms)
```

So that alone makes using C++ faster, but maybe not all that amazing, but if both the Javascript and the C++ loops (see the src) are commented out, and when only the array allocation is included:

```
    void doMkArray(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
    {
       v8::Isolate *I = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
       Local<Int32Array> testArray = Int32Array::New(ArrayBuffer::New(I, 4 
/*
...
```

Then the time changes to

```
  Performance Tests
    ✓ via javascript (62ms)
    ✓ via c++ (80ms)
```

In other words, simply allocating the array takes approximately 60ms in JavaScript, and 80ms in the C++ module. But that means that the rest of the time is the time spent in the loop, which is approximately 60ms in C++ and 110ms in Javascript. And so for actions that are predominately loops and calculations using direct buffer access, C++ is preferred.

Comment: question remains why the c++ version of allocating an array is actually slower than in javascript.